# I am hoping someone can shed some light on these nmap scan results

Tags: network, nmap

I am concerned that a friends computer may be compromised. They were complaining about the computer getting really hot, difficulty maintaining an online connection, finding unread non junk emails in the trash, etc..  so I just did a very basic nmap scan of their IP `nmap -Pn -A xx.xx.xx.xx`. The results of this are as follows:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE       REASON          VERSION
21/tcp   open     tcpwrapped    syn-ack ttl 64
22/tcp   open     ssh           syn-ack ttl 42  OpenSSH 5.5p1 Debian 6+squeeze3 (protocol 2.0)
53/tcp   open     domain        syn-ack ttl 42
80/tcp   open     http          syn-ack ttl 42  Apache httpd 2.2.16 ((Debian))
111/tcp  open     rpcbind       syn-ack ttl 42  2 (RPC #100000)
514/tcp  open     shell?        syn-ack ttl 42
3389/tcp filtered ms-wbt-server no-response
4899/tcp open     radmin        syn-ack ttl 105 Famatech Radmin 3.X (Radmin Authentication)

rpcinfo: 
   program version   port/proto  service
   100000  2            111/tcp  rpcbind
   100000  2            111/udp  rpcbind
   100024  1          38460/udp  status
   100024  1          48666/tcp  status
```

It also lists the ssh-hostkey and then underneath that are listings for ssh-dss and ssh-rsa. I don't really know enough to know what I'm looking at but several of these open ports have me concerned. I know this is not a ton of information, but based on this scan and keeping in mind that this person is not very computer oriented is there a cause for concern here?

Comment: In order to properly interpret a nmap scan we would need to know the proper context.  Is this a desktop machine? Is this a webserver?  What services do you expect to have running (webserver, ssh, etc.)?

Comment: That makes sense. This is a laptop machine running Windows 8. My friend doesn't have any knowledge of running  a web server or any of this stuff. When I asked about which ports are supposed to be open, the response I got was, "what do you mean port?" So as far as I can tell, the only services that should be running would be the basic out of the box services that the majority of computers are running if there is such a standard. I really have a hard time imagining them running any remote shell or Radmin software.

Comment: I think you've scanned his router, not his laptop. You're better off running a scan using anti-virus rather than using nmap.

Comment: I agree with paj28, the fingerprints identify the service versions as belonging to debian.  While the fingerprints are far from foolproof they're not usually totally wrong.  Double check that you've scanned the right host here.

Comment: This is not an OS fingerprint, but the OpenSSH banner. Normally (unless changed for obfuscation), this should speak the truth. And in this case alarming, because it is a very old and vulnerable version of OpenSSH. (On a no longer supported version of Debian). Whatever you have scanned (this is unlikely a Windows box), it is probably compromised and should be treated this way. It could also be this host is abused as stepping stone to an internal network which might causes the problems to his Windows box.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that open ports should not be alarming IN THE RIGHT CONTEXT. I perform pentests regularly and many of these ports are open for valid purposes. 514 is a little more uncommon, but not altogether unheard of for some applications, like gaming (if your friend games - this was not mentioned in OP) or sending syslogs.

With that being said, the context is important. Having port 80 and 4899 on a desktop, for instance, is a bit out of context - however, I have run some instances of software and used the localhost:80 to use a GUI (nodered, spiceworks inventory, etc). I agree with the comment above that this looks more like a router than a laptop. If the IP scanned ends in .1 or .254, it's almost certainly a router.

The more important question is not what ports are open, but what services and software are running behind them. Port 3389 is for RDP - is this a server that needs RDP, for instance? If not, you certainly want to disable RDP, as that presents an attack surface.

Instead of checking for open ports, use an AV scanner with up to date definitions and signatures. The trouble is that some malware blocks AV installs, so if you have trouble installing it, that would throw up red flags. I highly recommend malwarebytes as a good first step in scanning.

In the meantime, it would not hurt to disable your network adapters until you can run a full scan of your entire disk.